# Is it possible to have TextInput fields on a model that uses ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a website that allows users to create and store recipes. I have a recipe model and am using a custom 'through table' to have numerous ingredients for each recipe (with each ingredient having its own attribute like quantity and unit of measurement).

```
class recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='N/A')
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('ingredient', through='recipe_ingredient', related_name='recipes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe_name


class recipe_ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('recipe', related_name='recipe_ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('ingredient', related_name='recipe_ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('unit', related_name='recipe_ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} {self.unit} {self.ingredient}'


class unit(models.Model):
    measurement_desc = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.measurement_desc


class ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name
```

I'm then using a formset_factory, to allow the user to add multiple ingredients to a recipe dynamically.

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = recipe
        fields = ['recipe_name', 'description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3 create-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-9'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Field('recipe_name'),
                Field('description'),
                Formset('ingredients'),
                HTML("<br>"),
                ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'save')),
                )
            )


class IngredientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = recipe_ingredient
        fields = ['quantity', 'unit', 'ingredient']

IngredientFormset = inlineformset_factory(recipe, recipe_ingredient, form=IngredientForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

This works fine if I manually enter ingredients into the database but if I try and change the ingredient  inputs to TextInputs to allow the user to create new ingredients it won't save (due to those ingredients not being in the database. This is my createview:

```
class CreateRecipe(CreateView):

    model = recipe
    form_class = RecipeForm
    template_name = 'mealplanner/recipe_create.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(CreateRecipe, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ingredients = context['ingredients']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if ingredients.is_valid():
                ingredients.instance = self.object
                ingredients.save()
        return super(CreateRecipe, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('recipe-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Am I going about this completely wrong or is there a way to have django save the new ingredients to the database as the user creates new recipes?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is, iterate over the formset and verify that the recipe exists, if not, then create it:

```
def form_valid(self, forms):
    for form in forms:
       if not form.cleaned_data["ingredient"]: # ingredient does not exists
           # create it here
       ...
```